# Handle change and select list of options

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm trying to select an option from the list and click the button to confirm the selection. I save the selected option in the "pickedUser" object. But when I change the state of the "pickedUser", I think the render is start again and the list is like at the beginning. I just want to select the option and click on the button without restarting select list. If you can help solve the problem and point out the mistakes I need to correct in order to get better. Thanks!

```
//pickedUser saving selected option from list.
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      pickedUser:{
        name:"",
        email:"",
        uloga:""
      }, 
      isLoading: true,
      errors: null
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.routeChange = this.routeChange.bind(this);
  }
```

```
//In handleChange I'm trying to set a value I get from select to pickedUser.
async handleChange(event) {

    const eName = event.target.value.split(',')[0];
    const eEmail = event.target.value.split(',')[1];
    const eUloga = event.target.value.split(',')[2];
    await this.setState({
      pickedUser:{
        name : eName,
        email: eEmail,
        role: eUloga
      }
    });
  }
```

```
//And this is a part of my render.
render() {
    const { isLoading, users, pickedUser } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <select
          id="list"
          value={pickedUser}
          onChange={event => this.handleChange(event)}
        >
          {!isLoading ? (
            users.map((user, key) => (
              <option key={key}>
                {user.name},&emsp; {user.email}, &emsp; {user.role}
              </option>
            ))
          ) : (
            <p>Loading...</p>
          )}
        </select>
        <button id="b1" type="button"
          value={pickedUser}
          onClick={event => {
            this.handleSubmit(event);
            this.routeChange();
          }}>
          Sign in
        </button>
```

I wanted to function normally, that when I select the option, it stays selected, but it happens that when I select it, it is refreshed again.
I just have to tell that the value is good when the option is selected but the display is not.

Comment: What does `routeChange` method do?

Comment: Note that each time the state changes using `setState` the component is re-rendered. https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly

Comment: Is there any need for `handleChange` when clicking on the select? Since it will call the `setState` that will in return re-render the component. FYI, there is no need for an async function for the `handleChange`, you can remove the async and await.

Comment: 1)I call on the routeChange at onClick in button and I used it to transfer to the other page.

Comment: 2)I note that the component is re-rendering and I want to stop that when I select option.

Comment: As far as I can see there should not be any problem with this code, the DOM should not be changed when you click on the select. Can you create a reproducible code, using e.g. https://codesandbox.io/ ?

Comment: How you mean is there any need for handleChange? I must somehow to save the option I have chosen.

Comment: Create a form and pick up the selection when you click sign in. No need to store it in the state. https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: Yes, but I want to pick, for example, the name from the selected option, and on the next page I write a welcome {name}! That's why I would keep it in the some object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you only have to correct this line

```
<select
    id="list"
    value={pickedUser.name + "," + pickedUser.email + "," + pickedUser.role}
    onChange={event => this.handleChange(event)}
>
```

`value` should not be object (`pickedUser`), but it should be string.

This is [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/so56782409-yr4j4)

But I can suggest following:

1. Make `state.users` object (not array). Email should be unique, so it can be used as key. For example:

   ```
   this.state = { users: { "jack@mail.com": {name: "Jack", uloga: "aaa"},
       "mark@mail.com":  {name: "Mark", uloga: "aaa"} } }
   ```

   In this case you'll be able to extract user from `users` by it email.

   Object also support iteration like arrays useng `Object.keys(users)` or `Object.values(users)`
2. Use `email` as `key` for `<option>`. Index as keys is not good practice in React.
3. Add `id` to each `<option>` to easily identify selected option in event handler

Suggested version is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/so56782409modified-qrdq8)

Comment: Thanks a lot! You helped me and solved my problem. Also thank you for tips that are very useful.